# Autofac DI wiring up issue in webapi asp.net project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, .net-4.7.2

Having an issue getting a service instance in my controller. Followed the documentation from [autofac's website](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#) but still getting an error. `"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyAssembly.Controllers.HeartBeatController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'MyAssembly.IO.IConfig config' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyAssembly.IO.IConfig)'."`

Here is my `Global.asax` file

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);


        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();
        BuildServices(builder);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.EnsureInitialized();

        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));
    }

    private void BuildServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Config>().As<IConfig>().InstancePerRequest();
    }
}
```

And here is my interface definition and class. Which is defined in the same assembly.

```
public interface IConfig
    {
        string GetSetting(string key);
        T GetSetting<T>(string key);
    }

    public class Config : IConfig
    {
        public string GetSetting(string key)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        }

        public T GetSetting<T>(string key)
        {
            var setting = GetSetting(key);
            return setting != null ? (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(setting, typeof(T)) : default(T);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so ridiculous but I failed to build the services before the container. Oversight on my part and the below works.

```
BuildServices(builder);
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
config.EnsureInitialized();
```